# Using web sockets when running MVC .NET 4.5 project from visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, websocket, iis-express

I am trying to use web sockets in a MVC project but not able to get it running. I have followed the steps mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets.aspx.

I am using iis express (that comes with visual studio) and have enabled webscokets protocol support while installing IIS express. But the url `ws://localhost/api/Chat?username=xyz` is still not reachable

Comment: this will be hard to debug I guess - but as a first check please try to run IIS-expr (or VS) as an administrator - also do you see any errors? Where is the code, your config, ...?

Comment: It is just a blog post, so no promise it will work. Like the post suggested, SignalR, an official framework from Microsoft, is more suitable.